# Apache Lucene - S3 directory

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, lucene

### How to configure apache lucene data directory and index directory location as s3 location?

My java code will run on EC2 and apache lucene data directory and index directory location as s3 location.

Sample Java Code: 
from Local Diretory

```
String indexDir = "C:\\Lucene\\Index";
String dataDir  = "C:\\Lucene\\Data";
```

To S3

```
String indexDir = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-s3-demo/Lucene/Index";
String dataDir  = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-s3-demo/Lucene/Data";
```

highly appreciate any sample code.
And my java code for local storage [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_first_application.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to configure your dir path based on your target system.
Depending on what you work with you're able to achieve this with property or configuration files.

This path should be used for directory initialization.

```
Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(...); // use path here
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`lucene-s3directory`](https://github.com/albogdano/lucene-s3directory) which I wrote. It writes Lucene indices to AWS S3 directly and does not need a local filesystem. It's pretty early stage so use with caution.

```java
S3Directory dir = new S3Directory("my-lucene-index");
dir.create();
// use it in your code in place of FSDirectory, for example
dir.close();
dir.delete();
```